# bug or feature: Keywords in Document Properties was generated not properly

Tags: java, itext7

I use itext7 7.0.0

I followed the samples from [Writer properties of Chapter 7](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-7-handling-events-setting-viewer-preferences-and-writer-properties)

My findings are:

(1) If I wrote

```
PdfDocumentInfo info = pdfDocument.getDocumentInfo();
...
info.setKeywords("ab");
```

I get correct generated Keywords property.

(2) However if I wrote:

```
info.setKeywords("a\nb"); // I want to make a line break
```

The Keywords were then not properly generated, see this screenshot:
[image: Mis-generated keywords]

(3) If I wrote:

```
info.setKeywords("a;\nb");
```

The generated Keywords were again correct:
[image: Correctly generated keywords]

I am not sure whether this is a bug or feature, maybe we should not "\n" in this case to break lines.

Comment: do you mean that if you used `a\nb` it outputted twice?

Comment: yes, did you re-produce this?

Comment: No, I was just asking for clarification.

Comment: Please try with iText `7.0.1`. This duplication issue seems to be already solved.

Comment: I just tried 7.0.1, this problem is still there in my application.

Comment: Tested it with 7.0.1: it puts the correct sequence `(a\nb)` into the pdf. The other question is how this will be displayed by the reader program. Acrobat Reader shows the linefeed and puts additional quotes around the keyword, Evince shows the linefeed but without quotes, and PDF-XChange viewer ignores the linefeed.